# Error displaying the character Delta in postscript device

Tags: r, postscript, eps

I have a legend that contains the character `Δ` and I am unable to produce publication quality EPS Figures. PNG and TIFF runs fine. Is this a bug? Is there any quick workarround?

I am on Ubuntu Linux 64-bit, running 64 bit R 3.0.2

```
setEPS()
postscript("Figure 1.eps", horizontal = FALSE, onefile = FALSE, paper = "special")
plot(1,1)
legend("topleft", c("ΔValue"))
dev.off()


png("Figure 1.png")
plot(1,1)
legend("topleft", c("ΔValue"))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you create the delta symbol with the `expression` function:

```
plot(1,1)
legend("topleft", expression(paste(Delta, "Value")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @ECII I suppose postscript doesn't support large character sets. This possibly includes the character `Δ`.

Comment: postscript supports the full character set defined by the font.  My guess your base font doesn't even have a "delta". The working code probably switches fonts, using symbol font for the delta and whatever your base font is for the rest.